# Spinner OnTouchListener, nothing happens. Why?

Tags: android, spinner, ontouchlistener

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this code? Eclipse doesn't show any errors, but nothing happens when the spinner is clicked.

Code:

```
Spinner startTime = ( Spinner ) findViewById ( R.id.project_start_time);

    startTime.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Toast.makeText ( NewTaskActivity.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT );
            return false;
        }

    });
```

XML:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/project_start_time"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: I don't want to select an item (there aren't any), just the spinner.

Answer (score 4):

You just forget to call show() method on your Toast messege.

```
Toast.makeText ( NewTaskActivity.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

add `.show()` at the end of `Toast.makeTest()`

Answer (score 1):

You forget to call `.show()` method at end of the `Toast`.

```
Spinner startTime = ( Spinner ) findViewById ( R.id.project_start_time);

startTime.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText ( NewTaskActivity.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        return false;
    }

});
```